# Continuity correction factor adding or subtracting $0.5$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In this file :http://mkarefin.weebly.com/uploads/2/0/7/9/20793168/assignment_6-solution.pdf

At the solution of problem number 11 on top of  page 7. The author writes that 
$$p(x >200) =p(z>\frac{(200-0.5)-\mu}{\sigma})$$
Shouldn't the right answer be : 
$$p(x >200) =p(z>\frac{(200+0.5)-\mu}{\sigma})$$
I mean it is $200+0.5$ instead of $200-0.5$. It is not a typo because the author makes the same statement in the next question by putting $175+0.5$ instead of $175-0.5$.

**Context :** The problem here is one of approximation of binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ by the normal distribution $N(\mu=np,\sigma^2=np(1-p))$ and we have to take account of a continuity correction factor. My understanding is that this is done by approximating $p(x > n)$ as $p(x>n+0.5)$ (here the inequality $x>n$ is strict) this is to prevent the approximation from being too large than the real value. The author is subtracting $0.5$ instead of adding $0.5$, am I missing something thank you  for your help!

Comment: I agree, it should be $+0.5$. It would be $-0.5$ if it were $\geq$ instead of $>$. (The point is that you replace each integer $n$ with the interval $(n-0.5,n+0.5)$.)

Comment: I would just use the converse probability from the beginning. $P(X>200)=1-P(X\leq 200)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{200+0.5-180}{\sqrt{900*0.2*0.8}} \right)=1-\Phi(1.708333)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, presuming that "more than $200$" does not include $200$.

With the correct continuity correction you suggest, the calculated probability would be about $0.0438$ rather than the solution sheet's $0.0521$.  The actual binomial probability is closer to $0.0452$,  And this might matter if using a $95\%$ level of confidence

Using R:

```
> 1 - pnorm(200-0.5, 900*0.2, sqrt(900*0.2*(1-0.2)))  
[1] 0.05208128
> 1 - pnorm(200+0.5, 900*0.2, sqrt(900*0.2*(1-0.2)))  
[1] 0.04378725
> 1 - pbinom(200, 900, 0.2)
[1] 0.04519563
```

Comment: The author also presumes that it does not include 200 since he is using $>$ instead of $\geq$.